# AWS RDS SQL Server Migrate DB from Outside

Tags: sql-server, amazon-ec2, rds

Today, I am using `AWS EC2 DB Instance` for my database (SQL Server).

I want to change the instance and instead to use RDS instance for my SQL Server.

In order to complete the migration from EC2 to RDS I need to pass the database with all its tables/stored procedures/types/views etc.

I tried to backup the database of the EC2 instance and then restore it in the RDS instance but I get the exception:

[image]

Moreover, I tried to generate a script of the EC2 instance DB and then run the script on RDS SQL Server connection but it failed to run many of the scripts because of permission exceptions.

I also found an article from the [AWS documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/SQLServer.Procedural.Importing.html) that shows that it is possible to upload a backup to S3 bucket. But I couldn't manage to understand how to restore the backup from the S3 bucket in the RDS instance.

Please, help me figure out how to do it? I belive it must be possible and easy somehow.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *Did* you try the [restore commands](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/SQLServer.Procedural.Importing.html#SQLServer.Procedural.Importing.Native.Using.Restore) on the link you posted? Did you get an error? Did you use the correct bucket and file name? The screenshot you posted doesn't help since you didn't post the commands you tried to use. Scripting the database to avoid misconfigurations with restore isn't an option either - what happens when something goes bad and you have to actually restore your database?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Oh I didn't understand that the restore should be with command, I tried to restore it from URL (and this works only for Azure).
I will try to restore it with this command and will update if it works.
Thank you very much.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes, it works but I had to add first option group of restore-backup-SQL and attach it to the RDS instance.